# Trigger javascript on screen size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap nav-tab which shows / hides various tab-panes depending on the screen size (done so via Bootstrap breakpoints).

The problem I am facing is when the user is on a sm screen with the #hide-show tab-pane active and then she resizes the browser window to a lg screen (where #hide-show is now hidden), the #hide-show pane still remains active in the background.

Is there a way to toggle the active pane based on screen size or the display-type attribute of the #hide-show tab pane?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item d-lg-none">
    <a class="nav-link" id="hide-show-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#hide-show" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="d-block d-lg-none tab-pane fade" id="hide-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="hide-show-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Answer (score 3):

As Roberto pointed out, the window has [a native event for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

To use it, you'd use [`EventTarget#addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', event => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by toggling the active panes, but you can conditionally remove this class on certain breakpoints.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Toggle on mobile
  if (window.innerWidth <= 696) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.active')).forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });
  }
});
```

I'd recommend resorting to [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) if it's merely affecting the style in a predictable way.

```css
@media (max-width: 696px) {
  .active {
    /* Mobile style changes here */
  }
}
```